# How to use Percentage for android layout?

Tags: android, android-view, android-preferences, android-styles

How can we use **percentage** values for android view elements? something like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="75%"
        android:layout_height="50%"/>
```

Comment: Besides the library cited in the answers, you can use `android:layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout` to achieve a similar aim: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Containers/LinearPercent/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: @CommonsWare but how can we set both width and height in percent in single layout ?

Comment: @Cyanotis: No, other than to the extent that you nest `LinearLayout` containers and control percentages along both axes via `android:layout_weight`. There's no question that the new `android.support.percent` classes are more flexible. I simply wanted to point out the classic approach, given that some people are opposed to using libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok . I thought there is any another way. thanks for replay.

Comment: this is an old question but have not new answers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018:**

`PercentRelativeLayout` and `PercentFrameLayout` are deprecated. Consider using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

**Old Answer:**

So far Android Support library has limited on where to use this:

1. with `RelativeLayout`

   ```
   android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   ```
2. with `FrameLayout`

   ```
   android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
   ```

How to use it?

Well, first make sure to include the dependency at
  `build.grade(Module: app)` in your android app.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
}
```

Then navigate to your xml layout in this example (.MainActivity)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%"/>

  <Button    
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"
    app:layout_widthPercent="60%"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:layout_widthPercent="90%"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

For more detail please check [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/):

Answer (score 13):

The support library just added a percent layout.

It can be done like this

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html

Answer (score 11):

You can use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html), 
It is a recent undocumented addition to the [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), enables the ability to specify not only elements relative to each other but also the total percentage of available space.

Structure Is

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="#cecece"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_marginStartPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginEndPercent="25%"
        android:text="PercentRelativeLayout example"
        android:background="#bebebe"/>


</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The **Percent package** provides APIs to support adding and managing percentage based dimensions in your app.

To use, you need to add this library to `your Gradle dependency` list:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
    // or compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
}
```

For demo purpose you can visit Git [android-percent-support-lib-sample](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample).

Answer (score 10):

With both `PercentFrameLayout` and `PercentRelativeLayout` being deprected in 26.0.0, you need to use `ConstraintLayout` to size your TextView with percentage values.

`ConstraintLayout` is really powerful tool to build Responsive UI for Android platform, you can find more details here [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

Here is the example how to size your TextView(w=75%, h=50%) using ConstraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/ver_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/hor_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hor_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ver_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add `constraint-layout` dependency to your module `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    ...
}
```

Or edit your layout directly in Layout Editor, as shown below:

[image: Layout Editor]

As a result your `TextView` width is 75% of parent width and height is 50% of parent height:

[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]

Answer (score 5):

Google has new API called **[android.support.percent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html)**

Example [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/myTextView"
         app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: There are a few errors here. Your opening and closing tags are different (Relative/Frame), but more important, those attributes are wrong it should be `app:layout_widthPercent="75%" app:layout_heightPercent="50%"`

Comment: yup Edited that It was type mistake as I am Trying to copy the OPs example

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PercentRelativeLayout` It is a Subclass of `RelativeLayout` that supports percentage based dimensions and margins.

To use, you need to add this library to your `Gradle dependency` :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
}
```

Sample structure is

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```