# How to arrange two linear layouts inside a relative layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

The attached image contain **3** layouts

1. **Relative layout**
2. **Linear layout**
3. **Linear layout**

Both the linear layouts are of *same size* and are *overlapped*.

All i want to know is how to arrange those two linear layouts inside the relative layout so that Linear **layout 1** & **Linear layout 2** will have **90%** of parent height. Also **linear layout 1** must be aligned to the **top** of relative layout while **linear layout 2** to the **bottom** of relative layout.

Any simple working solution will be appreciated.( I'm a *newbie* to android studio)

[image]

Comment: Nesting layouts is bad for performances. Consider overlapping Views, in your RelativeLayout, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html):

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_heightPercent="90%"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_heightPercent="90%"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The order in which the LinearLayouts will overlap corresponds to the order in which they are defined.

Comment: Nice answer almost our answers are same @Svit, try to explain how things work, +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, What you can do is use **[PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)** instead of `RelativeLayout` so you can adjust that 90% height, and then use this property

```
android:layout_alignParentTop = true
```

for your first `LinearLayout` and

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom = true
```

for second `RelativeLayout`

It will stick your `LinearLayouts` inside `RelativeLayout` as you want.

See this questions for how to use PercentRelativeLayout [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36923661/5476209)

**[Sample Layout here](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample)**

And If you also want Layering effect as you saw in one of pic use

```
android:elevation  property on your both `LinearLayout`.
```

### Code taken from another answer by **@Svit** for full explaination

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_heightPercent="90%"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_heightPercent="90%"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Way

1. Set Linear Layout Height to your desired level (fixed)
2. Specify `android:gravity` property for both Linear Layouts (1'st Layout Top & 2'nd Layout Bottom.

Then you can get the required result.

Comment: but it will cause problem on different screens the aspect ratio wanted will not maintain accurately @Christlin

Comment: i don't think so, because you will be having different layout files for different screen density. So adjust your height property for each type of screens. Then it will be good.

Comment: but a long way, not preferable @Christlin

Comment: okay, no problem, yours will work. I already mentioned that this is another way :) @parmar

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph  Tried it ! But still both linear layouts are aligned at the top.

Note : One of the linear layout is a nested one.

Comment: Yes will work but efficiency matters a lot, Although good try @Christlin 
Welcome to SO

Comment: try fill_parent for Relative layout height