# How can I improve performance of my android Application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an application where whole data came from the API. I mostly used fragment in my application at some fragment my application did not take too much time. But at some Fragment It take to much time to display the Layout. When I debug the application I saw that data has came rapidly but it take time to display the data . And in the Log I got a message "this Application doing lot of task in its main thread". Is there any way to improve the performance of the application ?

Comment: move task away from main thread

Comment: All networking task I did in background thread.

Comment: As I told my application take time in displaying some data . Is this is the issue of complex layout?

Comment: as you haven't posted any code (which you should) so it is just a wild guess. May be you are doing some other time taking tasks like fetching contacts etc. They should also be moved to background thread

Comment: Do you use the attribute `weight` of `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: Yes , I used. Is It  creating issue?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives then use http://stackoverflow.com/a/36923661/4854450

Answer (score 0):

you can use volley libraries to download data fast and for image use picaso and for database use relm  database its fast api  dont use old style httpcliant or json parser its slow.and first display data from database then store data  of api in database and again dispaly from database in onpause method after some time(dippents on our data how much time tack to load ).if you have large data in json use pagination tachniq.

Comment: I used volley at some layout it work fine as I Mention above

Comment: relm 10 x  faster database

Comment: dislplay data first from db and store server datain background then display again after some time

Comment: see json responce time in postman or any other tolll if  json responce more then 2000 ms then you have to think about server responce

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am facing the same issues when I try to parse the JSON Results as a markers in GoogleMap.For <1000 Json Objects it works fine But when the Json Result Object Exceeds >1000 my app gets hangs and it takes too much of time to load. Here What I have done to fix the issue

> i am assuming you are deal with JSon Data.

1. Reduce the Size of JSon Results Based on Some Conditions.
2. Use small tags for JSon Lables(for Ex. instead of lable latitude use
   l,instead of longitude use lo)
3. Avoid HttpClient for Network Calls,Use Appropriate Network Library(like volly,Retrofit,OkHttp) based on Your Requirement  [NetworkLibraries Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley)
4. If you have any Calculations with the Result data Try to done it
   from the Server side as much as Possible
5. Remove Unwanted data in the JSON Result.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this guide line for Android app development [Click here](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices)