# Spinner or text view is not visible when i add spinner and textview in same xml

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i am developing a layout, which contains below item

In top, Horizontally 3 text views under that one listview.

if i make listview as a visible the top 3 textview getting hided.

if i make top 3 textviews as visible the listview getting hided.

can anyone help me make both textviews and listview visible?

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="sunday"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="jun 01, 2017"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holiday_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="New Yearr's day"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_holiday"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#999999"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/listbg"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you give weight and height to your LinearLayouts at the same time. If you want to have them weight you should use 0dp for height

Comment: There are no Spinners in xml file you shared but it's probably total height of TextViews and LinearLayouts exceeding the screen height. Check it and it will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will solve Your issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="sunday" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="jun 01, 2017" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holiday_col"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="New Yearr's day" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_holiday"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/listbg"
        android:divider="#999999"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PercentLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233266/how-to-use-percentage-for-android-layout) to set height of the views by 100% without using LinearLayouts with weights. You can also check [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) to see how it's implemented.