# Keep view the same on all devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

How can I change my activities xml file so that the view stays the same regardless of the size of the screen. What I mean is the location in which the buttons or text is. I want it to stay relatively the same distance and everything. How would I do that? Would relative layout work for that or do is there something else that I would have to do in order for the view to be the same on all devices?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:background="#2C3AAD"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="247dp"
    android:layout_height="243dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:src="@drawable/opengraph"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/autoclick"
    android:layout_width="49dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cursor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.991" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#2c3aad"
    android:maxHeight="62dp"
    android:maxWidth="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/singleclick"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:background="#2C3AAD"
    android:src="@drawable/singlecursor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.99" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/notes"
    android:layout_width="47dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="62dp"
    android:maxWidth="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />
```

Comment: ConstraintLayout is absolutely the way to go. Check out https://constraintlayout.github.io/. Everything you can do with percent and relative layouts can be done with constraints (and has the added bonus of better performance than nesting layouts).

Comment: please give your design.ConstraintLayout is best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use layout percentage if you want it to be same in other devices. Here are links that you could use for reference [Percentage layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233266/how-to-use-percentage-for-android-layout) and [Percent Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)