# Android. set textSize so it's height matches a percentage of it's parent layouts height - possible?

Tags: android, kotlin, autoresize, screen-size, text-size

My task is simple, but any solution seems very complex... I have an app that dynamically generates 17 tablerows with a textView/editText in each row. Right now the textSize is hardcoded to 20f for all textViews/editText - it looks decent on my phone but it is not very compatible with fx. a tablet. I want to set the textsize to a number that will make the height of the text 1/17 of its outer container. each tableRow will then fit perfectly on the screen no matter what size/resolution the device has.

[How it looks on different scrren sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n65V.png) - img

[How it should looks on different scrren sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hASnl.png) - img

and no matter what other kind of screen; inches, dimension, resolution etc. etc. the text line height should ALWAYS be 1/17 of the red box's height. Is this even possible?

I write in kotlin and my UI is dynamically generated, i create the rows & textViews like this:

```
fun createRow(label: String, tf: Typeface): TableRow {
        val row = TableRow(activity)
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border)
        gameSheetTable.addView(row)
        val tw = TextView(activity)
        tw.text = label
        tw.textSize = textSize
        tw.typeface = tf
        tw.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        textViews.add(tw)
        row.addView(tw)
        return row
    }
```

**I have tried:**

1. using different values for different screen sizes; hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi - This result was very ugly and did not work at all, the 10" tablet was recognized as a large device but had poor resolution so the text went way out of the screen, other 10" tables was ok. so this method is completle useless. right?
2. I hardcoded the textSize to be very small, and made a loop that would increase it by one for every cycle. Problem here is that the textView's are not rendered before the function returns. So the loop condition is never able to check if the new textSize matches 1/17 in height of the outer containers height. When debuggin and stepping over 'tw.textSize = newTextSize' which should also increase the height of the row but since it doesn't render nh = nameRow.height is still the same so the loop just runs in infinity...

`

```
fun resizeText(){ 
    val maxHeight = dgs_cointainer.height 
    var nh = nameRow.height 
    while(maxHeight > nh * 17){ 
        textSize += 1 
        editTexts.forEach { 
            et -> et.textSize = textSize 
        } 
        textViews.forEach { 
            tw -> tw.textSize = textSize 
        } 
    nh = nameRow.height } 
}
```

**DID NOT WORK**

3. (didn't try yet) then there is this "new" Autosizing TextView, but I can't find any examples to configure it to be 1/17 of somethings height and autosize to that, and I'm a bit confused if it will work on older devices since it states to require android 8.0 API level 26 ??? - can this do what i'm trying?

Comment: [did you have a look at this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233266/how-to-use-percentage-for-android-layout)

Comment: This is not really what i'm asking. I'm asking how to set a textsize that that will make the text's height corrospond to a percentage of the parent containers height.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent is a LinearLayout, use weights and weightSum with a 0dp height for the TextView.  This will make the textView take a percentage of the parent by weight/weightsum.

If the parent is a RelativeLayout, use PercentRelativeLayout from the support library instead, which has support for percentages.

If the parent is something other than those two, you'll have to see what the parent supports for layout options.

Comment: Hi, my textViews is inside tableRows which ofc is inside TableLayout... i guess i could make the table row's use weight on height so they would take equal amout of height which in total will be the full container right? then you suggest that i also put weight/weightsum on the textViews inside the table rows? that would make them grow in height to match parent and would also scale up the fontsize ? so the text becames bigger like in my image example?

Comment: I added weight to my tableRow's like so:
val params : TableLayout.LayoutParams = TableLayout.LayoutParams()
params.weight = 1f
val row = TableRow(activity)
row.layoutParams = params

This made all the rows 1/17 heigh - so i'm getting closer, and it already looks better. Thanks a lot for your tip!
How ever on large screens it still looks silly because the text is very small, is it now this "autosizingTextView" comes in play? or is there a way to allow the textsize to grow as its parent grows ?