# Error:(49, 39) Fraction types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value '50%')

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the widht on 50% on an androiyd layout file  this way

```
 android:layout_width="50%"
```

but I get this error

```
Error:(49, 39) Fraction types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value '50%').
```

How I have to set the width on 50%?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961355/115145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Percentage for android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233266/how-to-use-percentage-for-android-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Percentage layout? If so try this

```
 app:layout_widthPercent = "50%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library for this, since Android does not supply this by default. You might either need a or a `PercentRelativeLayout` or a `PercentFrameLayout` depending on your root layout.

Check this thread below:

[How to use Percentage for android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233266/how-to-use-percentage-for-android-layout)

Edit, thanks to @Eugene

This was deprecated in Android 8.0 and up, you can use a `ConstraintLayout` as well, as described here.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html

Comment: PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout were deprecated in 26.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Recently you were able to do it with PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout, but since they were deprecated in 26.0.0 the convenient way to set percentage value to your layout_width is to use guidelines which were introduced in ConstraintLayout

Here's my answer on another question on how to set percentage value https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865283/7158449